# Reseting password for Azure Linux ARM VM gives ERROR

Tags: linux, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am resetting the password of a `Linux(Redhat) VM in ARM Azure`. Using following command.

I am getting a error as below ...

> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> azure vm reset-access rgname vmname -u hadoop -p redhat@123
>   info:
>
> Executing command vm reset-access
>   + Looking up the VM "hadoop"
>   + Installing extension "VMAccessForLinux", VM: "hadoop"
>   error:   Long running operation failed with error: 'VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'VMAccessForLinu
>   x'. Error message: "Enable failed.".'.
>
> info:    Error information has been recorded to C:\Users\Amitkumar.patil.azure\azure.err
>   error:   vm reset-access command failed

Error File Contains

```
            2016-05-05T09:21:14.934Z:
            { [Error: Long running operation failed with error: 'VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'VMAccessForLinux'. Error message: "Enable failed.".'.]
              stack: [Getter/Setter],
              request: 
               { rawResponse: false,
                 queryString: {},
                 method: 'GET',
                 headers: { 'user-agent': 'WindowsAzureXplatCLI/0.9.15' },
                 url: 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/75706c1b-8db8-49f6-8295-1c36c0b4e0c3/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/eastus/operations/72d61126-96e0-407d-a28e-b724d7efee6e?api-version=2015-06-15' },
              response: 
               { body: '{\r\n  "operationId": "72d61126-96e0-407d-a28e-b724d7efee6e",\r\n  "startTime": "2016-05-05T09:19:40.0598247+00:00",\r\n  "endTime": "2016-05-05T09:20:59.4442674+00:00",\r\n  "status": "Failed",\r\n  "error": {\r\n    "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError",\r\n    "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension \'VMAccessForLinux\'. Error message: \\"Enable failed.\\"."\r\n  }\r\n}',
                 headers: 
                  { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                    pragma: 'no-cache',
                    'content-length': '378',
                    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    expires: '-1',
                    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains',
                    'x-ms-served-by': '0309f20e-ba97-4cfa-a387-af57e4db0559_131067724814019554',
                    'x-ms-request-id': '4e2f8f12-06e7-4b8c-b76e-0e9706c7b490',
                    server: 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0, Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0',
                    'x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-reads': '14851',
                    'x-ms-correlation-request-id': 'a0e647c1-afda-4f0f-a02c-bc3cf0bced14',
                    'x-ms-routing-request-id': 'NORTHCENTRALUS:20160505T092114Z:a0e647c1-afda-4f0f-a02c-bc3cf0bced14',
                    date: 'Thu, 05 May 2016 09:21:14 GMT',
                    connection: 'close' },
                 statusCode: 200 },
              message: 'Long running operation failed with error: \'VM has reported a failure when processing extension \'VMAccessForLinux\'. Error message: "Enable failed.".\'.',
              code: 'VMExtensionProvisioningError',
              body: 
               { operationId: '72d61126-96e0-407d-a28e-b724d7efee6e',
                 startTime: '2016-05-05T09:19:40.0598247+00:00',
                 endTime: '2016-05-05T09:20:59.4442674+00:00',
                 status: 'Failed',
                 error: 
                  { code: 'VMExtensionProvisioningError',
                    message: 'VM has reported a failure when processing extension \'VMAccessForLinux\'. Error message: "Enable failed.".' } },
              __frame: 
               { name: 'createOrUpdateVMExtension__18',
                 line: 248,
                 file: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\lib\\commands\\arm\\vm\\virtualMachine.js',
                 prev: 
                  { name: '_createOrUpdateExtension__38',
                    line: 1400,
                    file: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\lib\\commands\\arm\\vm\\vmClient.js',
                    prev: [Object],
                    calls: 1,
                    active: false,
                    offset: 9,
                    col: 19 },
                 calls: 0,
                 active: false,
                 offset: 4,
                 col: 88 },
              rawStack: [Getter] }
            Error: Long running operation failed with error: 'VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'VMAccessForLinux'. Error message: "Enable failed.".'.
              <<< async stack >>>
              at createOrUpdateVMExtension__18 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\commands\arm\vm\virtualMachine.js:252:89)
              at _createOrUpdateExtension__38 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\commands\arm\vm\vmClient.js:1409:20)
              at setExtension__24 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\commands\arm\vm\vmClient.js:979:10)
              at __26 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\commands\arm\vm\vm.js:555:18)
              <<< raw stack >>>
                at PollingState.getCloudError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\node_modules\ms-rest-azure\lib\pollingState.js:119:15)
                at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\node_modules\ms-rest-azure\lib\azureServiceClient.js:133:38
                at Object.async.whilst (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\node_modules\ms-rest-azure\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:621:13)
                at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\node_modules\ms-rest-azure\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:617:23
                at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\node_modules\ms-rest-azure\lib\azureServiceClient.js:109:20
                at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\node_modules\ms-rest-azure\lib\azureServiceClient.js:231:5
                at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\node_modules\ms-rest-azure\lib\azureServiceClient.js:399:12
                at retryCallback (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\node_modules\ms-rest-azure\node_modules\ms-rest\lib\filters\exponentialRetryPolicyFilter.js:140:9)
                at handleRedirect (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\node_modules\ms-rest-azure\node_modules\ms-rest\lib\filters\redirectFilter.js:36:9)
                at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\util\utils.js:482:7
```

Comment: Hi Folks, Could you please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I'd say that the 'azure vm reset-access' command has a bug. As the error message suggests, though, under the hood, it's just using the VMAccessForLinux extension, so you can use that directly to bypass the bug.

In Azure CLI 2.0, the command looks like:

```
az vm extension set -g YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --vm-name YOUR_LINUX_VM_NAME --publisher Microsoft.OSTCExtensions --name VMAccessForLinux --protected-settings '{"reset_ssh": true, "username": "YOUR_USERNAME", "password": "YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD"}'
```

It's been a while since I used Azure CLI 1.0, but If I recall correctly, it has an equivalent `azure vm extension set` command that takes the same parameters.

Hope this helps! For more examples of different configs (changing ssh keys and the like), check out this blog post:
https://negatblog.wordpress.com/2018/07/03/changing-admin-credentials-of-vms-and-scale-sets/